# onEditComplete does not work

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a **p-table** which entails **editable columns**. What I need to do is when value of a the field *Year* is changed, I can get and use it. To start, I would like to be able to show it on the console. To do this, I use `onEditComplete` funtion

**HTML file:**

```
    <p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Year</th>            
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr>
                <td pEditableColumn>
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input ">
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.id">
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{rowData.id}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
                <td pEditableColumn [pEditableColumn]="rowData"
 [pEditableColumnField]="'year'" (onEditComplete)="onEditComplete(rowData)">
                    <p-cellEditor>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.year" required>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{rowData.year}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                </td>
              <td pEditableColumn>           
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

**TS file:**

```
onEditComplete (event) {console.log(event);}
```

But by making changes to the *Year* field and then pressing tab or enter, I don't get any outputs.
Could you help me finding out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by removing `(onEditComplete)="onEditComplete(rowData)"` from `td` and adding `(onEditComplete)="onEditComplete($event)"` to `p-table`:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" (onEditComplete)="onEditComplete($event)">
      //........
      <td pEditableColumn [pEditableColumn]="rowData" [pEditableColumnField]="'year'" >
      //...
</p-table>
```

Comment: but is it triggered when losing focus?  Or must you hit enter to trigger the event?  For me (v6) you must press enter.